# i am facing this error in q learning how can i fix this?

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

**how to Fix this error occurring in Q-learning algorithm**

```
   **how to Fix this error occurring in Q-learning algorithm**
                action=np.argmax(Q[stateS,:])
    stateSprime, reward, done,     info = env.step(action)


 
    ---> 16     stateSprime, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

      ValueError:   too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: Please share more of your code, and your general approach.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, via the use of `env.step(action)` that you are using a Gym environment.
`env.step` unpacks 5 values instead of 4.

```py
observation, reward, terminated, truncated, info = env.step(action)
```

`terminated` and `truncated` both end the environment, but can be used in alternative settings to describe the cause of termination.